# Including base64-encoded image in ReportLab-generated PDF

Tags: python, django, reportlab, temporary-files, stringio

I am trying to decode base64-encoded image and put it into PDF I generate using ReportLab. I currently do it like that (`image_data` is base64-encoded image, `story` is already a ReportLab's story):

```py
# There is some "story" I append every element
img_height = 1.5 * inch  # max image height
img_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb', suffix='.png')
img_file.seek(0)
img_file.write(image_data.decode('base64'))
img_file.seek(0)
img_size = ImageReader(img_file.name).getSize()
img_ratio = img_size[0] / float(img_size[1])
img = Image(img_file.name,
    width=img_ratio * img_height,
    height=img_height,
)
story.append(img)
```

and it works (although still looks ugly to me). I thought about getting rid of the temporary file (shouldn't file-like object do the trick?).

To get rid of the temporary file I tried to use `StringIO` module, to create file-like object and pass it instead of file name:

```py
# There is some "story" I append every element
img_height = 1.5 * inch  # max image height
img_file = StringIO.StringIO()
img_file.seek(0)
img_file.write(image_data.decode('base64'))
img_file.seek(0)
img_size = ImageReader(img_file).getSize()
img_ratio = img_size[0] / float(img_size[1])
img = Image(img_file,
    width=img_ratio * img_height,
    height=img_height,
)
story.append(img)
```

But this gives me **IOError** with the following message: "*cannot identify image file*".

I know ReportLab uses PIL to read images different than jpg, but is there any way I can avoid creating named temporary files and do this only with file-like objects, without writing files to the disk?

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap StringIO() by `PIL.Image.open`, so simply `img_size = ImageReader(PIL.Image.open(img_file)).getSize()`. Its actually a thin wrapper around Image.size, as Tommaso's answer suggests. Also, there is actually no need to calculate the desc size on your own, `bound` mode of reportlab.Image could do it for you:

```
img_height = 1.5 * inch  # max image height
img_file = StringIO.StringIO(image_data.decode('base64'))
img_file.seek(0)
img = Image(PIL.Image.open(img_file),
            width=float('inf'),
            height=img_height,
            kind='bound')
)
story.append(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ReportLab but if you can use PIL directly this will work:

```
...
img = Image.open(img_file)
width, height = img.size
...
```

you can have a look here for PIL Image class [references](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me without PIL, as the image is already a JPEG:
raw just pulls the base64 string out of a dictionary.  I just wrap the decoded "string" in a StringIO.

```
        raw = element['photographs'][0]['jpeg']
        photo = base64.b64decode(raw)
        c.drawImage(ImageReader(StringIO.StringIO(photo)), 0.5*inch, self.y, height = self.PHOTOHEIGHT, preserveAspectRatio = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me. I'm using Flask with Google App Engine.

```
from reportlab.platypus import Image
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
import cStringIO
from base64 import b64decode

story=[]
encoded_image = "...."
decoded_img = b64decode(encoded_image)
img_string = cStringIO.StringIO(decoded_img)
img_string.seek(0)
im = Image(img_string, 180*mm, 100*mm, kind='bound')
story.append(im)
```

I have received the image from the client and saved in the database:

```
from base64 import b64decode
image = request.files['image'].read()
encoded_image = b64encode(image)
```